# WPF custom derived control style

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, styles

I have a custom control derived from Button:

```
    class MyControl : Button{}
```

And suppose, this class is empty (has no members).

In the application's main window resources I use ResourceDictionary that contains styles for most [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) controls (so called theme):

```
    <ResourceDictionary Source="BureauBlue.xaml" />
```

So, all controls on the window look like it is defined in that theme file. But the styles are not affected on MyControl controls. How can I do MyControl to look same as a Button controls?

Update: The style for Button in BureauBlue.xaml has no key and is defined in the following way:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{x:Null}"> ...</Style>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You override the DefaultStyleKey's metadata in your static constructor:

```
static MyControl()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
        typeof(MyControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));
}
```

Then, in your resources, you can base its style on the button:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type lcl:MyControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" />
```

I've tried in the past to override the DefaultStyleKey's metadata to point to the base class (Button in your case), but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but strange: if I define such style in Themes/Generic.xaml this gives no effect. And if I define this style in my Window or App resources, then everything is ok.

So, it is unclear to me the situation when I create my ButtonEx control in one assembly and will use it from another one, so how could I then define in my control library that my ButtonEx control should look as Button by default?

Answer (score 3):

The TargetType property doesn't work for classes that derive from the specified type. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592844/applying-a-style-to-all-derived-classes-in-wpf)

Answer (score 3):

I use [SetResourceReference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.setresourcereference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
SetResourceReference(StyleProperty, typeof(Button));
```

Answer (score 2):

For doing this completely in code [this answer on another forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e16ef092-a62b-4f45-bc63-6fee5f68b7d9/how-to-make-custom-derived-wpf-controls-to-use-the-same-style-and-wpf-theme-as-their-base-not?forum=wpf) works

```
this.Style = new Style(GetType(), this.FindResource(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Button)) as Style);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if style for Button is there in your BureauBlue.xaml
and remove x:key attribute from the style if it is there

Comment: The style for Button in BureauBlue.xaml has no key and is defined following wise:
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
...</Style>