# WPF Custom Control : Events for the controls defined in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, custom-controls

Im making a CustomControl derived from `ComboBox` :

```
public class CBT : ComboBox
{
    static CBT()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CBT),
         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CBT)));
    }
}
```

And Im editing the default `Style` of the `ComboBox` (..a copy from Blend).

So If I am to add a `Button` inside the `Popup` of the ComboBox, and would like to have its `Click` registered, What is the best way that i should follow ?

I tried :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ui_test"
                xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2"
                x:Class="ui_test.CBT">
```

and changing to :

```
public partial class CBT : ComboBox {}
```

But throws error that `Partial declarations of 'ui_test.CBT' must not specify different base classes`

Help me out please ? :)
Thanks in advance :)

## EDIT: How to handle the Button's Events is what i donot know :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i ended up with :
Commands were overkill for the Task i had to get done

```
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        popup = this.GetTemplateChild("PART_Popup") as Popup;

    }
```

simply pass in the name of the Control you want to get hold of :)

Answer (score 0):

you need a style , you cant set class to a resource dictionary like that 
see this topic similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729161/wpf-custom-derived-control-style) or read [Mosers guide](http://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html)

 from the article:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type yourcontrol}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type yourcontrol}">
                ... 
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: None of them helps me with adding `Events` to Controls defined inside the CustomControl..