# How to make a WPF style inheritable to derived classes?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In our WPF app we have a global style with `TargetType={x:Type ContextMenu}`. I have created a MyContextMenu that derives from ContextMenu, but now the default style does not apply.

How can I tell WPF that I want MyContextMenu to inherit the default style from ContextMenu? Hopefully I can do this from within my control itself (via static ctor metadata override or something?) and not have to mess around in any xaml.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you have a Style defined in your application like so:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}" ...
```

Then that is an implicit Style, not a default Style. Default Styles are generally located in the same assembly as the control or in matching assemblies (i.e. MyAssembly.Aero.dll).

Implicit Styles are not automatically applied to derived types, which is probably what you are seeing.

You can either define a second Style, like so:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ContextMenu}" TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}" ...
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyContextMenu}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContextMenu}}" ...
```

Or you can leverage the Style property of your control. You could do the following from XAML

```
<local:MyContextMenu Style="{DynamicResource {x:Type ContextMenu}}" ...
```

or you can do this in your MyContextMenu like so:

```
public MyContextMenu() {
    this.SetResourceReference(StyleProperty, typeof(ContextMenu));
}
```

Comment: The last hunk of code was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Mr. Naked!

Comment: This is one of those instances where I wish I could upvote an answer like 11 times. Thanks.

Comment: Nice trick, so we can inherit implicit style from explicit one.

Comment: Googled like a mad dag. `SetResourceReference` to the rescue!! Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you use `DynamicResource` in the XAML insertion of `MyContextMenu` and `StaticResource` in the implicit style definition? I tried both in XAML insertion, and both seem to work.

Comment: Followup: never mind, I got it. `DynamicResource` is needed to go look up the implicit style for `ContextMenu`. `StaticResource` worked for me because I use explicit style names.

Answer (score -1):

In complement to CodeNaked's excellent suggestions, I tried specifying `Style` in the XAML part of `MyContextMenu`:

```
<ContextMenu x:Class=LocalProject.MyContextMenu"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AdelSoft_WS_FRA_Test.Composants"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Style="{DynamicResource {x:Type ContextMenu}}">
```

The compiler warned me that it cannot resolve the resource, but at runtime it looks quite able to.

Naturally, you can also use

```
             Style="{StaticResource ContextMenuStyleName}">
```

if you use style names.