# Content page property not set with implicit style

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, prism

Using Prism.Forms 6.2 and Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.118 pre-1 when I set the content page padding in the application resource file it is not followed globally only for the content page padding. All other resource properties are flowing correctly. Here is my code for the app.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<prism:PrismApplication xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Class="MyNamespace.App"
        xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Unity;assembly=Prism.Unity.Forms"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyNamespace">
    <prism:PrismApplication.Resources>
        <!-- Application resource dictionary -->
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converter:DebuggingConverter x:Key="localDebuggingConverter"/>
            <local:ItemTappedEventArgsToItemTappedConverter x:Key="SelectedItemConverter" />
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" >
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <!--iOS default is 17 and is not the same size as android 14. If FontSize is left at default it will be larger on iOS than android-->
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                            iOS="14" 
                            Android="14">
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center">
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPage">
                <Setter Property="Padding">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                            iOS="5, 28, 5, 5"
                            Android="5, 8, 5, 5"
                            WinPhone="5, 8, 5, 5" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </prism:PrismApplication.Resources>
</prism:PrismApplication>
```

Here is my xaml view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
        xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyNamespace"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True" 
        x:Class="MyNamespace.Views.ChooseProfileView">
    <!--<ContentPage.Padding>
        If I set the content padding this way it is rendered correctly. When this is commented out as it is now the padding is not set by the application resource (implicit style).
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                            iOS="5, 28, 5, 5"
                            Android="5, 8, 5, 5"
                            WinPhone="5, 8, 5, 5" />
    </ContentPage.Padding>  -->
    <ContentPage.Content>
<!-- whatever content. The padding set here is displayed correctly-->
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

TargetType in style is set to ContextPage but the real type is ChooseProfileView.

[Xamarin.Forms.Style.TargetType Property](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Style.TargetType/)

> Developers should be aware that implicit styles are only applied to the specific type that is described by Style.TargetType, and not to types that inherit from it.

Comment: I want the content padding in all content pages of the app, not just the ChooseProfileView.

Comment: XAML does not support this explicitly.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780605/how-to-make-a-wpf-style-inheritable-to-derived-classes and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592844/applying-a-style-to-all-derived-classes-in-wpf

Comment: So am I misunderstanding these docs [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/application/) then?    `ContentPage` is a native Xamarin.Forms element. I'm not sure where the `ContextPage` comes in at.    I also wanted to mention that before I implemented Prism in this app that this styling worked correctly.