# WPF style not applied at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-style

I am trying to apply a `Style` on a `CheckBox`. The problem is: the `Style` is applied at design-time, but not at run-time. It's working only if I'm putting the `Style` in MainWindow.xaml.

I have a `Style` in a resource dictionary. Here it is, in App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <Style x:Key="ToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
              <Storyboard x:Key="OnChecking">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="slider" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                  <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="25"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
              <Storyboard x:Key="OnUnchecking">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="slider" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                  <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="slider" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)">
                  <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
                </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </ControlTemplate.Resources>

            <DockPanel x:Name="dockPanel">
              <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
              <Grid Margin="5,5,0,5" Width="50" Background="#FFC0CCD9">
                <TextBlock Text="ON" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,3,0"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,0,0,0" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Text="OFF" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="slider" Width="23" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="3,3,3,3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="1,1,1,1">
                  <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                      <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                      <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0"/>
                      <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
                      <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                  </Border.RenderTransform>
                  <Border.BorderBrush>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                      <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="#FF4490FF" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                  </Border.BorderBrush>
                  <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                      <GradientStop Color="#FF8AB4FF" Offset="1"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="#FFD1E2FF" Offset="0"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                  </Border.Background>
                </Border>
              </Grid>
            </DockPanel>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                  <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnUnchecking}" x:Name="OnUnchecking_BeginStoryboard"/>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                  <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnChecking}" x:Name="OnChecking_BeginStoryboard"/>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
              </Trigger>
              <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
              </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

This is how I am trying to apply style:

```
<CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ToggleButton}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Test"/>
```

**UPDATE:**
I found out that the `Style` is not applying at run-time when my startup location is not App, but the class Program.cs that I created.

Comment: it looks fine to me, also at runtime: what's exactly not applied?

Comment: Your exact XAML functions perfectly at both design time and runtime when I past it into a sample application.  I would look for something else in your application that might be overriding your `ToggleButton` style at runtime.

Comment: It's working only if I'm putting style in MainWindow.xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that style is not applying at runtime when my startup location is not App, but the class that I created Program.cs.

Answer (score 0):

Give a name to your checkbox and try applying style dynamically.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chckbx1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource ToggleButton}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Test"/>
```

In code behind:

```
chckbx1.Style = (Style) FindResource("ToggleButton");
```

Comment: I am getting exception that style is cannot be found

Comment: @user2412672 I tried it myself working fine for me. I don't know how you are using it or where you are using it .if you are using it in a class  which is not deriving from Window class(as in general) then it will not work as Style derives from   System.Windows namespace.Could you paste the whole code where you are using this.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this occur *when the style `TargetType` is for a base class, not the specific derived class*. In this situation the designer showed me the style applied as it was intended, but at runtime it was not.

I was using VS2015 designer in particular.

I eventually resolved this by following advice in [Applying a style to all derived classes in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592844/applying-a-style-to-all-derived-classes-in-wpf) and [How to make a WPF style inheritable to derived classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780605/how-to-make-a-wpf-style-inheritable-to-derived-classes).